# Clock and Data direction in MII and RMII Interface

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, ethernet

I have this question in the Ethernet MII interface.

Consider the TX lines between the MAC and the PHY. On the TX lines, data is being transferred from the MAC to the PHY. So, how does the transmission start? Does the PHY sends the TXCLK first? Upon receiving the TX clock, the MAC gets to understand the frequency of the TXCLK and then transmits the data on the TX lines or how does the transmission of data happen on the TX lines? Like could you explain to me the step-by-step sequence of clock and data movement on the TX and RX lines with respect to CLK to understand a little more clearer, please?

Comment: Which chip you are using? Does it have a data sheet?

Comment: https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/KSZ9131#document-table - This series of ICs.

Comment: In most cases, the clock needs to be there generally, even when idling. Think the receiver - it needs to see transitions at a txclk-derived rate to train its own clock recovery to be able to receive correctly when suddenly data starts

Comment: Could you please write an answer in simple terms @MarcusMüller

Comment: Does the MAC receiver in MII get the clock from RXC line or does CDR from the RX data lines?

Comment: Your chip has RGMII so it does not match your question which is about MII and RMII. The datasheet still has nice diagrams and text that answers the questions how data is transmitted on RGMII bus, and where does the receive clock come from. So do other data sheets. What is it in the data sheets that you need "more clearer"? Normally you don't need to know this, if you just connect two chips together as drawn in the diagrams, it will just work.